# Where do the NSLogs show up in xcode 6

Tags: xcode, nslog

I have a project in Xcode with a ton of NSLogs, that have always worked... in Xcode 5. I updated to Xcode 6 and my app doesn't want to log anything. I have the debug area up and both sides are showing, I've tried pushing all the buttons down there and it still doesn't show up.

It's really frustrating because I need the NSLogs so I can debug my app.

Comment: The logs show up in the same place they always have. Nothing has change in this regard between Xcode 5 and 6.

Comment: Ok it must be a glitch in the new xcode 6 versions because I restarted Xcode a few times and it worked