# Viewing NSLog in Xcode 6.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I had to update to finish up an app I have been working on for almost a year and now none of my NSLog info shows up in the bottom pane. It's kind of ridiculous. I have Googled and can't find anything salient. Is this buried somewhere that someone can point out please? Build 6A317

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079914/where-do-the-nslogs-show-up-in-xcode-6

Comment: Jesus. OK thanks for the heads up. I will just do some re-starts and see if I can get it to work. Thanks.